# Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have issues implementing CloudTrail via Cloudformation, with a Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket error being thrown when I try to launch the model.

Here is the configuration from the BucketPolicy:

```
"LogBucketPolicy": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "Bucket": {
                "Ref": "LogBucket"
            },
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                        },
                        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "LogBucket"
                                    }
                                ]
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                        },
                        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                        "Resource": {
                            "Fn::Join": [
                                "",
                                [
                                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                    {
                                        "Ref": "LogBucket"
                                    },
                                    "/AWSLogs/139339407673/*"
                                ]
                            ]
                        },
                        "Condition": {
                            "StringEquals": {
                                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I have copied the template from AWS examples, but let me know if I did a mistake in the implementation.

Edit: The error is not thrown by the bucket policy, but by CloudTrail. Here is the configuration of the bucket:

```
"Trail": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudTrail::Trail",
        "Properties": {
            "SnsTopicName": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "Topic",
                    "TopicName"
                ]
            },
            "IsLogging": true,
            "S3BucketName": {
                "Ref": "LogBucket"
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": [
            "LogBucket"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Where could I find a more detailed error message? So far, I can only the one available when I create the pile, and it is not as detailed as I wish it would be.

Comment: If you click on the CREATE_FAILED portion, it may show up what happened. Your bucket policy looks good. I tried the same thing in my CloudFormation and it created the bucket policy without any issues.

Comment: I unfortunately don't get much more details. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSVd3oI5J8lL3U6kckc1ZMb9519DWl7m/view?usp=sharing) is the screenshot of the detailled errors, I can't see anything more. 
One thing I should have clarified is that the error is trown by CloudTrail and not the bucket.

Comment: I see that you have defined an account number `139339407673`. Is this the account number where you are deploying the CloudFormation stack? If the account number is incorrect, you will receive this error. Instead, try using: `{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"}`.

Comment: I have switched the code to the {"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"} in the section, didn't make a difference.

Comment: You have defined `DependsOn` in CloudTrail resource in the template. Can you change its value to: `"DependsOn": ["LogBucketPolicy"]`.

Comment: Well, I get a new error, but it's not connected to the Trail, so I guess it was the issue. Thanks a lot Krishna!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Krishna has mentioned, the error came from the fact that I didn't put the dependence of the BucketPolicy. When this was done, the stack was deployed with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and it seems to be working for me. Can you try this?

```
{
  "Parameters": {
    "LogBucket": {
      "Description": "Name Bucket.",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "LogBucketPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
      "Properties": {
        "Bucket": {
                "Ref": "LogBucket"
        },
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "LogBucket"
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
              },
              "Action": "s3:PutObject",
              "Resource": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                  "",
                  [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::",
                    {
                      "Ref": "LogBucket"
                    },
                    "/AWSLogs/139339407673/*"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                  "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error arises. Thank you for the help still!

Comment: I guess, the problem is with your bucket name ? what is the input you give?

Comment: I changed it as Krishna suggested above, which seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the dependency issue mentioned in the accepted answer, the error can also comes from different cases of wrong configuration of the S3 policy.

For example, if we look at the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20131101",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20131101",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/[optional] myLogFilePrefix/AWSLogs/<account-id>/*"
      "Condition": { 
        "StringEquals": { 
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control" 
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking at the `Resource` block of the 2nd statement:

```
 "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myBucketName/[optional] myLogFilePrefix/AWSLogs/<account-id>/*"
```

**Passing wrong values to the Resource block** like bad prefix (my case) or forgetting the `"*"` postfix (like mentioned [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14989) in last scenario) **can lead to the error**.

(*) Example taken from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-set-bucket-policy-for-multiple-accounts.html).